# Login Activity with Android Studio - When to implement?

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication

I am starting to code in Android Studio and I was wondering when was the right time to implement the Login Screen.

I have three questions that I would love if someone could answer:

1. Is it correct to use the default android studio login activity?
2. Is that activity good and can be modified according to my needs easily? Or should I build it from scratch for a more personalized login?
3. When is the right time to implement it? At the first steps of development, towards the end...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can use it and it´s easy to modify.
2. Yes you can use it and it´s easy to modify.
3. You can implement it when you want. I recommend you to use FireBase(firebase auth). This will help you too much.

Comment: Thank you! it helped